# Android Espresso testing app flow

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotium, android-testing, android-espresso

I use Espresso to test a lot of activities and transitions between them. I want to write different test for those activities and link the  Activity Intents to the corresponding test cases.

1 . Activity A (testActivityA runs)
2. ActivityA launches ActivityB (testActivity B) should be called

is it possible to do this with espresso or any other test framework?

Comment: It is possible with espresso.Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20696266/5105754)