# Duplicate of 'Android Espresso testing app flow'

Tags: android, android-espresso

## [Android Espresso testing app flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131857/android-espresso-testing-app-flow/41939987#41939987)

I use Espresso to test a lot of activities and transitions between them. I want to write different test for those activities and link the Activity Intents to the corresponding test cases.

1 . Activity A (testActivityA runs) 2. ActivityA launches ActivityB (testActivity B) should be called

is it possible to do this with espresso or any other test framework?

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question, but I wouldn't recommend that. Your should test each activity independently and use mocking objects. Hint Espresso allows your to start an activity.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you call other activities by pressing a button or clicking at some view, then it is possible in Espresso. You can try "Espresso Test Recorder" for creating different cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should test each activity independently of the others. If you need them to react to incoming intents, you can do that using [Espresso Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents.html).