# Is it possible to perform end to end testing with Espresso in Android?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

In the past week I was searching to find helpful information regard end to end testing on Android. Although I found UI Automator, it didn't catch my eyes.

I'm working on an application that its happy path contains 6 activities. I want to create my Booking object in main screen and move it across happy path to check its status. I think I'm able to mock server response with [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver). All samples I see are testing one activity at time.

So my question is am I able to test all these activities (happy path) in one test? If yes is there any sample for that?

Comment: Kind of disappointing to see such a broad question (and a request for offsite resource!) given your rep.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I don't think that is a broad question actually. Someone might ask I'm looking for a testing Tool for Android, what are they? so you say junit, Espresso, robolectric. Same to my question, I did a lot of research in past week and didn't find anything helpful in end to end testing except UIAutomator which I didn't find it strong enough. So, I want to know does anyone have had same experience and how he solved the issue?

Comment: *"Someone might ask I'm looking for a testing Tool for Android, what are they?"* - and they'd be off-topic, too.

Comment: if you are mocking... it is an integration test and not an E2E one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espresso should be able to work with multi activities. But when you say end to end test, you want to treat the app as a black box and run a stand alone testing framework against it?

In that case, Espresso doesn't seem to be the solution though you sure can use it to exercise your happy path through a number of different activities.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm not doing black box thing. For end to end I mean testing a path such as happy path Via Espresso. I want to create an object in main screen and pass it to other activities across happy path and examine it's status on those activities. Do you have a link to some multi activity tests?

Comment: @Hesam, just found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427411/testing-multiple-activities-with-espresso

Comment: thanks, yup, this is my last achievement too :( http://stackoverflow.com/q/35419824/513413

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is yes. Espresso works well for testing interaction between activities in a single app.

UI Automator is intended for testing the interaction of multiple apps. For example, if your app uses the camera, UI Automator is ideal for testing the interaction between your app and the camera. The down side is that a pure UI Automator test knows nothing about the inner workings of your app. It can search for views based on the view hierarchy, but not with any knowledge of resource ids and such.

On the other hand, Espresso can find views based on their ids and other attributes that are available within your app. It can click on a button or another view which launches another activity and then interact with that activity. Espresso can only work with the views in your own app.

Espresso and UI Automator can be used together. You can use UI Automator to launch an Intent to another app (such as the camera) and interact with it. When the flow of execution returns to your own app, you can then use Espresso to check the results. Even for testing within your own app, I find the UiDevice class from UI Automator handy for manipulating the device, such as causing an orientation change.