# ViewPager and TabLayout inside CoordinatorLayout results to NoMatchingViewException

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, coordinator-layout

I'm doing instrumentation test using espresso, problem is it can't find the ids of the CoordinatorLayout/ViewPager/AppBarLayout/TabLayout, this is a new screen/activity, shown after I successfully performed click on a button from my main screen.

```
onView(withId(R.id.main_content)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed())); //tried all the IDs
```

This always results to NoMatchingViewException

I've tried to explicitly use the string values of my tabItems but still results to same error

I've read here [Testing multiple activities with espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427411/testing-multiple-activities-with-espresso), there shouldn't be any problem even if this not the main activity specified in my ActivityTestRule

My xml file:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/main_content">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab1"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tab2"/>

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager android:id="@+id/container"/>
```

This is my first time using espresso. Am I missing something?